# 500 internal server error. CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following react component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import PageHeader from '../../components/utility/pageHeader';
import Box from '../../components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../components/utility/layoutWrapper.js';
import ContentHolder from '../../components/utility/contentHolder';
import basicStyle from '../../settings/basicStyle';
import IntlMessages from '../../components/utility/intlMessages';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {tenantid: '', tenanturl: '', tenantpassword: '' };
    this.handleChangeTenantUrl = this.handleChangeTenantUrl.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTenantPassword = this.handleChangeTenantPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTenantId= this.handleChangeTenantId.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  };


  handleChangeTenantUrl(event){
    this.setState({tenanturl: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeTenantPassword(event){
    this.setState({tenantpassword: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeTenantId(event){
    this.setState({tenantid: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("TenantId", this.state.tenantid);
    formData.append("TenanrUrl", this.state.tenanturl);
    formData.append("TenantPassword", this.state.tenantpassword);

    const options = {
      method: 'put',
      data: formData,
      config: {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
    };

    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (!this.isCancelled) {
          this.setState({ data: responseJson });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  upload(e){
      let data = new FormData();
      //Append files to form data
      let files = e.target.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append('files', files[i], files[i].name);
      }      
  }

  render(){
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { rowStyle, colStyle, gutter } = basicStyle;

    return (
      <div>
        <LayoutWrapper>
        <PageHeader>{<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}</PageHeader>
        <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
          <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={24} style={colStyle}>
            <Box
              title={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
              subtitle={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
            >
              <ContentHolder>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                  TenantId:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.tenantid} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantId} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantUrl:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.tenanturl} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantUrl} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantPassword:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.tenantpassword} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantPassword} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  Certificate:
                  <input onChange = { e => this.upload(e) } type = "file" id = "files" ref = { file => this.fileUpload } />
                </label>             
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
              </ContentHolder>
            </Box>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </LayoutWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then I get a 500 server error:

https://screencast.com/t/n7VRzxSSi6

Cors is already enabled on the web api.

https://screencast.com/t/3Fl70yX0awO

The web api code is like this:

```
public class TenantController : ApiController
    {
        public async Task<List<Tenant>> GetTenants()
        {
            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            return await tenantStore.Query().Where(x => x.TenantId != null ).ToListAsync();

        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTenant(string tenantId)
        {
            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            var tenant = await tenantStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TenantId == tenantId);
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(tenant);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult>  PutTenant([FromBody]Tenant tenant, HttpPostedFile certificateFile)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageKey"].ToString());
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificatesContainer"].ToString());

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

            // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = certificateFile.ContentType;
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(certificateFile.InputStream);

            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            tenant.CertificatePath = blockBlob.Uri;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            //if (id != tenant.TenantId)
            //{
            //    return BadRequest();
            //}

            var added = await tenantStore.AddAsync(tenant);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent); 
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTenant(string id, Tenant tenant)
        {
            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var result = await tenantStore.UpdateAsync(tenant);
            return Ok(result);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteTenant(string tenantId)
        {
            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            await tenantStore.RemoveByIdAsync(tenantId);// Removes an entity with the specified ID
            return Ok(tenantId);
        }
    }
```

I attached the debugger after publishing, but the code is never hit in visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your state to `this.state = { TenantId: '', TenanrUrl:'', TenantPassword:''};` but you are using `tenantid`, `tenanturl`, and `tenantpassword` in your code.

Since `tenantid`, `tenanturl`, and `tenantpassword` are not initially in your state, you will begin to give `undefined` to your inputs until you call `setState` and update it. This will make the inputs go from uncontrolled to controlled.

You can fix it by changing your initial state to have default values for `tenantid`, `tenanturl`, and `tenantpassword` instead:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { tenantid: '', tenanturl: '', tenantpassword: '' };
  this.handleChangeTenantUrl = this.handleChangeTenantUrl.bind(this);
  this.handleChangeTenantPassword = this.handleChangeTenantPassword.bind(this);
  this.handleChangeTenantId= this.handleChangeTenantId.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
};
```